# Does the Angular route url has to be the same as the node express route to 'talk' to the backend?

Tags: angularjs, express, post, routes

Angular:
The url in my route in angular is '/auth/login', the route in the backend is '/login' -it all works but I just wonder why as both url's are different -how does the front end talk here to the backend?
Or does it work because both url's have /login (so whatever comes before-in this case: the /auth doesn't matter)?
Thank you.

```
....
auth.login = function(email, password) {
        return $http.post('/auth/login', user)
        .then(function(response){
            $rootScope.currentUser = response.data;
        })
  }
....
```

backend:

```
app.post('/auth/login', function (req, res, next) {  
   User.findOne({
    where: req.body
  })
  .then(function (user) {
      if (!user) {
      res.sendStatus(401);
    } else {
      req.session.userId = user.id;
      res.sendStatus(204);
    }
  })
  .catch(console.error)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works because once angular is loaded, any changes to the client-side url do not result in the browser making a server request.  The only request the browser makes to the server is for the index.html + any resources (js, css, images) it uses.

For more information on how this works, please see the *Hashbang & HTML5 Modes* section of the [$location guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

The link between client + server API only happens when you make `$http` requests from angular.  With `$http` requests you are specifying the exact URL of the API endpoint you want to request.

The front-end and back-end/API URL's do not need to have anything in common.  The only thing to be aware of is that the URL you use for the `$http` requests is pointing to a valid URL of your back-end API.

The only exception to all of this is if you have coded your app to do some kind of magic where you use the current browser URL to decide which API endpoint to hit.  This is a very rare case, and if your app is doing something like this, you will for sure know about it (because you would have had to custom build that functionality!)

Hopefully that clears it up for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that fronted and backend Url's don't have to have anything in common- lets say i make a $http request to /allusers and on my backend I have a route to get what I want (in this case all users) but the url is lets say /user --then the request will never 'get to the right endpoint?! Just like in my case- how does the http request /auth/login end up talking to /login?

Comment: angular handles the /login URL to make it load a state (as defined by whatever router you are using - most commonly ngRoute or ui-router).  That state causes a controller to load (either a route/state controller or some nested directive controller).  That controller makes an asynchronous `$http` request to the /auth/login API end-point.

Comment: To put it as simple as possible - /login front-end URL makes an `$http` request to API endpoint /auth/login - but really, *any* front-end URL could make that same `$http` request to /auth/login

Comment: The angular front-end can make `$http` requests to any back-end API endpoint from anywhere in its app.  You need to think of the front-end and back-end as separate apps that just talk to each other through API requests.

Comment: I don't understand then if ANY front end url could make the request to /auth/login -where is the connection? There are lets say 10 'api endpoints' /auth/login, /auth/signup, /shop , /users etc. If my my $http request url is for example '/people' (since you said it doesn't have to have the same url) how will the request go to the /auth/login and not to another one ??

Comment: The URL you put in the `$http` request matches exactly the API endpoint's URL.  The URL you type in the browser can be anything your angular app is coded to handle.  Read about [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) if you are still confused.  This is incredibly simple.  $location handles browser routing, $http handles async requests.  If you don't understand the difference, you need to study more until you do.

Comment: Also please see [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) OR [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) depending on which your app uses.  The app's routing module is what translates browser URL's into the pages to render.  From within any of those pages, you can make `$http` request to an API URL.

Comment: That was my question -if the $http request url has no be the same. I got confused because you kept saying it doesn't matter and both url don't have to be the same.